# How to format minutes to hours - using moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using moment.js.

I get minutes (max 1440) and i wanted to format that in hours in specific format.

Something like this:

420 minutes is: **07:00**

1140 minutes is: **24:00**

451 minutes is: **07:31**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const time = 1140;

console.log(getTime(time));

function getTime(minutes) {
  let hours = parseInt(minutes / 60);
  hours = hours < 10 ? `0${hours}` : hours;

  let min = minutes % 60;

  min = min < 10 ? `0${min}` : min;

  return `${hours}:${min}`;
}
```